# Can I have my table create data automatically, based on a different data on the same record?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say my table contains two attributes (columns). "Number" and "Number in Words". Can I have it so whenever I insert the data "1" in the "Number" column, the mysql table would automatically fill in "one" under the "Number in Words" column, in the same record?
When I enter in "3", the mysql table would automatically fill in "three" under the "Number in Words" column.
"4" to "four", "5" to "five", etc.

Don't get sucked into my example, by the way. I don't want a way to translate numbers into it's word form; I'm really just looking for a way to create an if statement of some sort. I would manually need to set the rules beforehand, that "1" would get me "one, "2" would get me "two", and so on.

Hope it makes sense, as I know very little of mysql.

Comment: How many species of "Number" you have?

Comment: "species"? Not sure what that means, sorry. In any case, I don't think it matters. Perhaps, I gave a poor example, because I'm really just wondering if I can create an if statement of that sort.

Comment: Does mysql have triggers?  That sounds like you need a trigger.

Comment: You can, but if you end up with hundreds or thousands of these rules, you'd be better off just doing the conversion in your client upon insert.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a `After Insert Trigger`.  Here is an example of the After Insert trigger:

http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-insert.shtml

[MySql Create Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

If you know the rules before the Insert as you stated in your question, then I would use a trigger.

Comment: I'm reading through your link, but it seems to be way over my head. Can you show me exactly how to do what I want? As I think what I want is simple enough.

Comment: This might give you a broader understanding of Triggers:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger#Triggers_in_MySQL

Comment: unfortunately I don't have time to code something up for you.  there are a lot of examples online if you google it or even here on SO. I can try to get to it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function with the logic and use it as the second column:

```
select number, number_to_words(number) as words
from t
```

MORE ELABORATED:

How to create the function using a slightly modified code from from JNK's answer:

```
create function number_to_words (num int)
returns varchar(100) deterministic

return case num
    when 1 then 'one'
    when 2 then 'two'
    when 3 then 'three'
    when 4 then 'four'
    when 5 then 'five'
    when 6 then 'six'
    when 7 then 'seven'
    when 8 then 'eight'
    when 9 then 'nine'
    when 0 then 'zero'
    else null
    end
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a `CASE` statement.  This is valid in `SQL Server`, should work similarly in `MySQL`:

```
DECLARE @num INT

SET @num = 1

INSERT INTO MyTable (Number, NumInWords)
SELECT @num, CASE   WHEN @num = 1 THEN 'One'
                    WHEN @num = 2 THEN 'Two'
                    WHEN @num = 3 THEN 'Three'
                    WHEN @num = 4 THEN 'Four'
                    WHEN @num = 5 THEN 'Five'
                    WHEN @num = 6 THEN 'Six'
                    WHEN @num = 7 THEN 'Seven'
                    WHEN @num = 8 THEN 'Eight'
                    WHEN @num = 9 THEN 'Nine'
                    WHEN @num = 0 THEN 'Zero'
                    ELSE NULL
                    END
```

Comment: What would be different about the MySQL version?

Comment: @user - not sure, I don't have a copy of MySQL to play with.  `CASE` I am pretty sure is ANSI standard, not sure if variable declarations are different.  Try it as written and see.

Comment: I knew my example would come back to bite me hah. How would you change your Case statement, if instead of dealing with numbers, you were dealing with, say, animal types. So "cat" would get "mammal", "salmon" would get "fish", etc. I'm not working with integers.

Comment: @user - just change it to `WHEN @variable = 'Cat' then 'Mammal' WHEN @variable = 'Salmon' then 'Fish'` etc

Comment: Wouldn't you need to change to DECLARE @num INT, though? I thought int implied integers.

Comment: @user - yes, you would need to change it to the correct datatype as well.

Comment: Well, I set the datatype to varchar, and it doesn't appear to be working =/ .

Comment: @user - I will probably need more info, like sample code posted into your original question

Comment: Hmm, why did you set @num = 1, anyway? I don't know what SET does, but it seems unnecessary, at a look of your code.

Comment: It was just an example...the `SET/DECLARE` portion is irrelevant to the logic.